# Snakemake workflow, ChildIOException or MissingInputException

Tags: workflow, snakemake

I am trying to add a file renaming step in my current workflow to make it easier on some of the other users. What I want to do is take the `contigs.fasta` file from a spades assembly directory and rename it to include the sample name. (i.e `foo_de_novo/contigs.fasta` to `foo_de_novo/foo.fasta`)

here is my code... well currently.

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

import os


def is_file_empty(file_path):
    """ Check if file is empty by confirming if its size is 0 bytes"""
    # Check if singleton file exist and it is empty from bbrepair output
    return os.path.exists(file_path) and os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta", sample = config["names"]),

rule fastp:
    input:
        r1 = lambda wildcards: config["sample_reads_r1"][wildcards.sample],
        r2 = lambda wildcards: config["sample_reads_r2"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        r1 = temp("clean/{sample}_r1.trim.fastq.gz"),
        r2 = temp("clean/{sample}_r2.trim.fastq.gz")
    shell:
        "fastp --in1 {input.r1} --in2 {input.r2} --out1 {output.r1} --out2 {output.r2} --trim_front1 20 --trim_front2 20"

rule bbrepair:
    input:
        r1 = "clean/{sample}_r1.trim.fastq.gz",
        r2 = "clean/{sample}_r2.trim.fastq.gz"
    output:
        r1 = temp("clean/{sample}_r1.fixed.fastq"),
        r2 = temp("clean/{sample}_r2.fixed.fastq"),
        singles = temp("clean/{sample}.singletons.fastq")
    shell:
        "repair.sh -Xmx10g in1={input.r1} in2={input.r2} out1={output.r1} out2={output.r2} outs={output.singles}"

rule spades:
    input:
        r1 = "clean/{sample}_r1.fixed.fastq",
        r2 = "clean/{sample}_r2.fixed.fastq",
        s = "clean/{sample}.singletons.fastq"
    output:
        directory("{sample}_de_novo")
    run:
        isempty = is_file_empty("clean/{sample}.singletons.fastq")
        if isempty == "False":
          shell("spades.py --careful --phred-offset 33 -1 {input.r1} -2 {input.r2} -s {input.singletons} -o {output}")
        else:
           shell("spades.py --careful --phred-offset 33 -1 {input.r1} -2 {input.r2} -o {output}")

rule rename_spades:
    input:
        "{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta"
    output:
        "{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

When I have it written like this I get the `MissingInputError` and when I change it to this.

```
rule rename_spades:
    input:
        "{sample}_de_novo"
    output:
        "{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

I get the `ChildIOException`

I feel I understand why snakemake is unhappy with both versions. The first one is becasue I don't explicitly output the `"{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta"` file. Its just one of several files spades outputs. And the other error is because it doesn't like how I am asking it to look into the directory. I however am at a loss on how to fix this.

Is there a way to ask snakmake to look into a directory for a file and then perform the task requested?

Thank you,
Sean

***EDIT File Structure of Spades output***

```
Sample_de_novo
  |-corrected/
  |-K21/
  |-K33/
  |-K55/
  |-K77/
  |-misc/
  |-mismatch_corrector/
  |-tmp/
  |-assembly_graph.fastg
  |-assembly_graph_with_scaffolds.gfa
  |-before_rr.fasta
  |-contigs.fasta
  |-contigs.paths
  |-dataset.info
  |-input_dataset.ymal
  |-params.txt
  |-scaffolds.fasta
  |-scaffolds.paths
  |spades.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, spoke too soon. It didn't name the output directory correctly, so I moved it to the `params` and, now, finailly is working the way I wanted.

```
rule spades:
    input:
        r1 = "clean/{sample}_r1.fixed.fastq",
        r2 = "clean/{sample}_r2.fixed.fastq",
        s = "clean/{sample}.singletons.fastq"
    output:
        "{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta"
    params:
        outdir = directory("{sample}_de_novo/")
    run:
        isempty = is_file_empty("clean/{sample}.singletons.fastq")
        if isempty == "False":
          shell("spades.py  --isolate --phred-offset 33 -1 {input.r1} -2 {input.r2} -s {input.singletons} -o {params.outdir}")
        else:
           shell("spades.py --isolate --phred-offset 33 -1 {input.r1} -2 {input.r2} -o {params.outdir}")

rule rename_spades:
    input:
        "{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta"
    output:
        "{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta"
    shell:
        "cp {input} {output}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta` to be the output of spades and parse its path to get the directory that will be the argument to `spades -o`. Snakemake won't mind if there are other files created in addition to `contigs.fasta`. This should run `--dry-run` mode:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta', sample=['A', 'B']),

rule spades:
    output:
        fasta='{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta',
    run:
        outdir=os.path.dirname(output.fasta)
        shell(f'spades ... -o {outdir}')

rule rename:
    input:
        fasta='{sample}_de_novo/contigs.fasta',
    output:
        fasta='{sample}_de_novo/{sample}.fasta',
    shell:
        r"""
        mv {input.fasta} {output.fasta}
        """
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately, it returned the same ChildIO error. I think the main issue is, because I never call the fasta output snakemake doesn't no where to get it from. Even if I just list it in the output. If I try to explicitly add to the output spades fails. Also the output of spades is more than that one file. It looks like this

Comment: I added the file structure to the main text to clarify

Comment: Sean, I edited my answer - see if helps

Comment: That worked in the dry-run, but in the test run it failed. However I keep with the same thought and named the `outdir = directory("{sample}_de_novo")` and that seems to be working. For some reason before the output was still getting pasted to snakemake as the file and not the directory.